# Add a dot every 3 characters counting backwards

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
32323
43434343
34343434
111134343434
.
.
.
```

And want my file to look like this:

```
32.323
43434.343
34343.434
111134343.434
.
.
.
```

How can I add a dot every 3 characters backwards?
I thought of maybe dividing every character by 1000? But couldn't find and option to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using sed;

```
sed 's/...$/.&/' file
32.323
43434.343
34343.434
111134343.434
```

Using awk:

```
awk '{printf "%.3f\n", ($1/1000)}' file
32.323
43434.343
34343.434
111134343.434
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sed` regex in `awk` too:

```
awk '{sub(/...$/,".&")}8' t
32.323
43434.343
34343.434
111134343.434
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use so called *parenthesized sub-expression*.

```
$ sed -e "s/\(...$\)/.\1/" file
32.323
43434.343
34343.434
111134343.434
```